# How to find the largest sum and smallest positive difference?

Tags: algorithm, math, addition, subtraction

Using the numbers 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, and 4 once each, find the following:

a) The largest possible sum

Is there more than on solution that gives the largest possible sum? How do you know it's the largest possible sum?

b) The smallest possible (positive) difference

Is there more than one solution? How do you know it's the smallest possible difference?

The numbers must be 3 digits. For example, 965 + 784 or 879 - 654

Comment: Seriously, you don't need a computer to solve this. Try posting at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sometimes the order doesn't matter. For example: 975 + 864 = 1839 but also 964 + 875 = 1839. In this particular case, since the two numbers are symmetrical and both 3-digits, all that matters is that you distribute the highest priority digits evenly between the two numbers and you are done, at least for the largest sum part. The smallest positive difference is a bit more tricky, I'll admit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not software development.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm interesting

#### Difference:

If you always take tupels `(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3)` for `a_1a_2a_3-b_1b_2b_3`, the difference is:

```
100*(a_1-b_1)+10*(a_2-b_2)+(a_1-b_1)
```

So for the smallest difference I guess this should be fullfilled: `-(a_2-b_2) > -(a_3-b_3) > (a_1-b_1)`:

```
(a_2-b_2) = 4-9 = -5 = d_2
(a_3-b_3) = 5-8 = -3 = d_3
(a_1-b_1) = 7-6 =  1 = d_1
```

giving you `745-698 = 47` which is the only smallest because in all other variants `d_2` will be bigger or `d_3` will be bigger or even `d_1`.
Also its unique (so just one solution) because it's asked after the positive difference, so you cannot switch the numbers.

#### Sum:

So for the sum we got:

```
100*(a_1+b_1) + 10*(a_2+b_2) + (a_2+b_2)
```

so now: `(a_1+b_1)>(a_2+b_2)>(a_3+b_3)`:

```
a_1+b_1 = 8+9 = 17
a_2+b_2 = 7+6 = 13
a_3+b_3 = 4+5 = 9
```

so it's `964+875 = 975+864 = 1839`, it's not unique, but still the biggest.
For you can change `b_i` and `a_i` you have `2^3` possiblities to build this sum.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure try all combinations and remember the best solution. but when you smart then you can avoid it by:

1. max sum is 975 + 864 = 1839

   - or any combination that evenly distribute bigger numbers to higher digit positions
   - just like Shashank Gupta wrote in a comment
2. the min positive difference is similar 745 - 698 = 47

   - the second number (without first digit) must be as big as possible
   - the first number (without first digit) must be as small as possible
   - the first digits must differ only by 1
   - after some thinking you should come to the same result

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for algorithms, here is a brute force solution in python:

```
In [1]: from itertools import permutations
In [2]: def gen_pairs():
   ...:     for p in permutations('987654'):
   ...:         yield int(''.join(p[:3])), int(''.join(p[3:]))
In [3]: '%i = %i + %i' % max((a+b, a, b) for a,b in gen_pairs())
Out[3]: '1839 = 975 + 864'
In [4]: '%i = %i - %i' % min((a-b, a, b) for a,b in gen_pairs() if a>b)
Out[4]: '47 = 745 - 698'
```

This just gives you the minimum and maximum values. To check for uniqueness:

```
In [4]: [(a,b) for (a,b) in gen_pairs() if a+b == 1839]
Out[4]: 
[(975, 864),
 (974, 865),
 (965, 874),
 (964, 875),
 (875, 964),
 (874, 965),
 (865, 974),
 (864, 975)]
```

Note that these are just 4 solutions if you do not count the swapped answers.

```
In [5]: [(a,b) for (a,b) in gen_pairs() if a-b == 47]
Out[6]: [(745, 698)]
```

So the difference has a unique solution.

I think it is more elegant to solve this problem by logical reasoning, as shown by the others. This just proves that they were right.